# compare two triangles that vary in size and rotation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

i am developing an application in which my system will accept two images of triangles. both the tringle are similiar but rotated. i want to prove that the images are same. what's the logic in MATlab?

Comment: What's the logic? then-> put it in Matlab.

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you need help finding the correct rotation value or proving the fact once you got the rotation right?

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Comment: after i have done with the rotation part of the triangles, i have to prove that the images are same

Answer (score 0):

Try using a corner detector to get the 3 verticies of the triangle. From here you can easily find the length of all three sides

(this is a random internet image, not a matlab result) [image]

if you have the coordinates of A,B,C you can find the lengths AB BC CA. Using trig you can find the angles at the verticies. Then simply compare these properties between the two triangles. You would have to try all combinations, for example AB of triangle one might match AB,BC,or CA of triangle two.

If you want to find similar triangles (angles only) simply ignore the length and use the angles you found only. IF you want exact matches use the length AND the angles.

Using properties of the triangles seems easier than any other image processing method I can think of. Good luck

Comment: The Cosine Rule is explained here... http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.07/h/lucy1.html

Comment: i used imrotate to rotate one of the images till both the images look like. however, how do my system detect the angle at which both the images tune to the same orientation look like

Comment: I suggested my approach because yours is much more difficult. First you need to rotate the triangle (say 5 degrees per iteration) then do **correlation** for every single x,y value of your image. That is one complete iteration, rotate another 5 degrees and repeat. After that you have to find the maximum correlation for all x,y and all angles. That will tell you the closest match. That doesn't mean they are the same triangle, it just means they are the most similar. This problem gets even harder if you need to scale the triangles.